# Rspec mocking block on stub not being yielded

Tags: ruby, rspec, block, yield, stub

So i have two calls to a method called retry_with_timeout that takes a block and executes until the block returns true or a value other than nil (i.e false will result in a loop) or until a timeout occurs

Sample class:

```
def do_the_thing
  retry_with_timeout(10, 5) do
    case something
      when 1
        false
      when 2
        false
      else
         raise
    end
  end

  retry_with_timeout(30, 10) do
    case something_else
      when 1
        false
      when 2
        false
      when 3
        true
      else
         raise
    end
  end
end
```

Spec class:

```
it "should pass when the thing is 3" do
  model = test_model #creates a double and stubs all of the necessary common methods

  t_model.stub(:retry_with_timeout).with(10, 5).ordered
  t_model.stub(:retry_with_timeout).with(30, 10).and_yield().ordered

  expect { t_model.do_the_thing }.to be(true)
end
```

I get an error because the '3' case isn't in the first block, thus the 'else' is called...

I need to skip the first and evaluate in the second block.... I have tried EVERYTHING and I am LOSING MY MIND!!!! Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've answered my own question... Turns out there are some features that aren't documented... In order to return then yield, one must do it the following way:

```
t_model.stub(:some_method).and_return("Cool", "Awesome", and_yield(foo))

#Just for informations' sake
t_model.stub(:some_other_method).and_return("FOO", "BAR", raise_error)
```

its added as a return item for some reason and ***ISN'T DOCUMENTED ANYWHERE!!!!!***